# Template render on HTML AND CSS using Google App Engine

Tags: python, css, google-app-engine, django-templates

I'm currently working on my website hosted on GAE.
It has not been update since a while, so now, I'm trying to made a refresh of it :D

To do the trick, I try to use the MVC model using Python and WSGI, WebAPP2 and Render.Template.

Everything goes right, except for the CSS part.

Indeed, I can't render some part of my CSS using the GAE (django) method.
My Python controller is calling the HTML file and replace the variables by the dict() values correctly.

But now, and to be able to only have restricted amount of CSS file, I'm trying to do the same thing.

Unfortunatly I don't know how I'm suppose to call the CSS File.

I'm currently calling my CSS on my HTML as usual:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/struct/index.css">
```

And trying to dynamically render this part of the file:

```
header#navigation{
height:auto;
min-height:480px;
width:100%;
min-width:100%;
background-image:url('/assets/img/content/{{content_cat_name}}/cat_img.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
background-size:contain;
background-color:#efefef;
}
```

and everything is then call by my python code like this:

```
class URIHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self, subdomain, page):
    name = subdomain
    pattern = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../views' ,'index.html')        
    template_values = {
            'content_cat_name':name,
            'cat_menu_title':name,
            'cat_menu_text':name,
    }

    self.response.out.write(template.render(pattern, template_values))
```

So, if someone could help me to correctly call my CSS and replace the variables using my python script, I'll be really happy :D
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to dynamically generate your CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`template.render` can only replace tokens in the file that you specify in the `path` parameter (the first parameter). You're serving the .css file out of a static directory, so no token replacement happens, because that file's not getting passed through that code.

You could inline the parts of your CSS that contain tokens in your index.html file.

Comment: Ouch -_-' I'll have to create css files for each categories...
Inline replacement of CSS properties are a little bit ugly, I rather prefer generating a css for each categories.

But many thanks for your help :D

Comment: Further if you import a file template.render treats it as static and will not render any tokens in it.

Comment: Why not just have a single CSS file, with rules based on class for each variant?

Comment: @MarkFinch : I do not understand your assumption, what did you try to point out?


NickJohnson: You mean a rules based generation into the HTML page?
If it is, yes, that what I've choose to do finally ;-)

Comment: @DrI if you use `{% include 'myfile.html' %}` directive to import a file. The myfile.html can not contain any directives, it can only contain static content.  This getting back to your question of wanting to render partial css.  It is tempting to think you can create a master.css file with directives to import other supplementary css files that contain more directives, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @MarkFinch, Thanks for your answer.
Indeed, you can perform such a things using the include directive as you can see it there:

[link](http://tutos-django.com/2011/11/28/lencapsulation-des-templates/)

I'm sorry, it's in French, but the author just made a POC using django and generating a unique template page for the whole site using include directive hosting skeleton pages where you can find variables directives.

Comment: @NickJohnson Yeaaah, that what I've done instead of creating multiple file, I've just created multiple classes called depending of my variable as you suggested it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I was having what I think is the same problem. I found this [GAE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles) very helpful. In short you need to go into your app.yaml file create a new handler:

```
url: /foldername
  static_dir: foldername
```

And then in your link tag:

```
href="foldername/index.css"
```

Comment: Well, in theorie that would be a solution if you generate the whole css file, the handler would be able to completly generate a specific css file depending of your handler but on my case I tried to dynamically generate only few directive arguments like the background one. I've finally used a css preprocessing system (sass) to solve this problem. Anyway, thanks for your interest on this topic. I've move on another project now (java one).